# Cannot parse date....in android

Tags: android, parsing, datetime

here is the code

```
    public static final String KEY_DATE_TIME = "reminder_date_time";
    SimpleDateFormat datetimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_FORMAT) ;

    try {
    String dateString = reminder.getString(reminder.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ReminderDbAdapter.KEY_DATE_TIME));

    Date date =  (Date) datetimeFormat.parse(reminder.getString(dateString);

    mCalendar.setTime(date); 
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        Log.e("edit_activity", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
```

it is not parsing date as all the values are fetched but date is not parsed so logcat is showing an error...help me out

Comment: put logcat & also tell what u want to do

Comment: 06-10 21:38:47.108: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at com.maddy.task_reminder.edit_activity.populateFields(edit_activity.java:267)

Comment: i just want to parse date from the string thats it....and string has both time and date